# Variables from geocoding not defined, how to call them correctly?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm try to learn javascript and using Google Maps API, and it seems I'm stuck on a (hopefully) simple issue.

I have wrote this function to obtain geocode coordinates:

```
function codeAddress() {
    var st = document.getElementById('start').value;
    var dest = document.getElementById('end').value;

geocoder.geocode( { 'address': st}, function(results, status) {
 var startCoded = results[0].geometry.location;
    var startLng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    var startLat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();   
 document.getElementById("content1").value = startCoded;

});
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': dest}, function(results, status) {
    var endCoded = results[0].geometry.location;
    var endLng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    var endLat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();        
    document.getElementById("content2").value = endCoded;
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
var lngSpan = startLng - endLat;  
var latSpan = startLat - endLng;
console.log(endCoded);
  }

});
    }
```

But I get this error: 
    ReferenceError: startLng is not defined

I understand it is related to the fact that I need a callback to read them, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just how you're declaring the variables (they're local to your functions instead of global). Try:

```
var startLng, startLat, endLng, endLat;
function codeAddress() {
    var st = document.getElementById('start').value;
    var dest = document.getElementById('end').value;

geocoder.geocode( { 'address': st}, function(results, status) {
 var startCoded = results[0].geometry.location;
    startLng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    startLat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();   
 document.getElementById("content1").value = startCoded;

});
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': dest}, function(results, status) {
    var endCoded = results[0].geometry.location;
    endLng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    endLat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();        
    document.getElementById("content2").value = endCoded;
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
var lngSpan = startLng - endLat;  
var latSpan = startLat - endLng;
console.log(endCoded);
  }

});
    }
```

Comment: Great! You can click the checkmark next to the question to indicate your question has been resolved.